# How to get list of ports which are in use at server from Delphi

Tags: delphi, winapi, command-line

I need to deal with the result of a command line like this: netstat -aon in Delphi, parse it and get to know all the ports already in use.
Is there a library or component around that does that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get this info you can use these WinAPi functions

- [AllocateAndGetTcpExTableFromStack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365804%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [AllocateAndGetUdpExTableFromStack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365807%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [`GetTcpTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366026%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [`GetUdpTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366033%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Wich are located in the `Iphlpapi.dll` (Windows Api IP Helper) library.

for a delphi translation of these functions you can check the `JwaIpHlpApi` unit wich is part of the [`JEDI API Library`](http://jedi-apilib.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Will try that and get back with the results. Thanks.

Comment: Hi there - is there anything wrong (or even everything) with the code I'm using:
var
  pTable: PMIB_TCPTABLE;
begin
  size := 100000; // ?????
  GetTcpTable(pTable, size, True);

The result is a huge number on the first field of pTable and only one entry on the second field, which is another record.

Comment: @Ronaldo, check this link http://smeschini.altervista.org/download/netstat32.php for a sample application using the GetTcpTable.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Jedi Api Lib, better to use existing header translations than everybody doing their own!

btw: we also keep a blog http://blog.delphi-jedi.net/ and the main page for Jwa is http://blog.delphi-jedi.net/jedi-api-headers/

Comment: In Windows vista and later, AllocateAndGetTcpExTableFromStack
AllocateAndGetUdpExTableFromStack are deprecated.  You should use [GetExtendedUdpTable][1] and [GetExtendedTcpTable][2] instead. 


  [1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365930%28v=VS.85%29.aspx
  [2] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365928%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: JEDI API library link is OOD - it still works but redirects to (as of right now): https://sourceforge.net/projects/jedi-apilib/